# Extracting image source from string in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape image sources from different website. I used `rvest` to do that. The problem I encounter is that I have a vector `string` containing the source but I need to extract the source from it.
Here are the first few entries:

```
> string
{xml_nodeset (100)}
 [1] <td class="no-wrap currency-name" data-sort="Bitcoin">\n<img src="https://s2.coinmarketc ...
 [2] <td class="no-wrap currency-name" data-sort="Ethereum">\n<img src="https://s2.coinmarket ...
 [3] <td class="no-wrap currency-name" data-sort="Ripple">\n <img src="https://s2.coinmarketc ...
```

What I need is basically the part coming after `src="`, so for the first one `"https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1.png"` (the console doesn't show the full strings but this what appears after the dots `...` and there comes more stuff after it as well).

Any help is appreciated as I am a bit stuck here.

Comment: From which website?

Comment: You can use `rvest` for this.. But if you need a regexp, you can do `sub(".*(https:)","\\1",string)`

Comment: It is from https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/. Alright, I will give that a try.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't quite do it, this is what I get `"https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1.png\" class=\"currency-logo-sprite\" ...` with some more html

Comment: just add `sub(".*(https.*png).*","\\1",string)`

Comment: `xml2::read_html("https://coinmarketcap.com/coins/") %>% rvest::html_nodes("td > img") %>% rvest::html_attr("src")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(rvest)
read_html("https://coinmarketcap.com/coins/")%>%
     html_nodes("td img")%>%html_attr("src")

  [1] "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1.png"            
  [2] "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1.png"   
  [3] "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1027.png"         
  [4] "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1027.png"
  [5] "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/52.png"           
  [6] "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/52.png"  
  [7] "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1831.png"         
  [8] "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1831.png"
    :
    :
    :
    :
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, a regular expression should do it:

```
myhtml <- gsub('^.*https://\\s*|\\s*.png.*$', "", string)
myhtml <- paste0("https://", myhtml, ".png")
```

The first line will extract the part of the string contained between `https://` and `.png`, and the second one will paste them back into your string in order to have a valid source, i.e. with `https://` and `.png` at the end.